# How to implement a customized sortable and expandable list in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to implement a list customized like below. You should be able to sort items on a given field by clicking on a header.
A line should also be expandable. When a user clicks on a +, the line should expand and disclose more information under its field2 value.

[image: my need :]

I have tried to use a ListView in a GridView. For each column, I have defined a template (a template for field1 values with the + on the left, one for field 2 values and one for field 3 values). With this implementation, my problem is "how to expand one line".

I also looked at the ListBox component, but I need to create headers manually and align the content. I also need to sort manually. It doesn't seem to be a good solution to me.

Do you have any better idea, or any advice?

Answer (score 2):

The correct base Control appears to be the `DataGrid`.
It will provide you with the functionality like sorting on headers, etc.

You will have to modify its `ControlTemplate` through a style if you want it to look like in the screenshot.

As an inspiration how you could ge the detail expansion, the following article could help you:

[Grouping in DataGrid in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/grouping-in-datagrid-in-wpf/)

You can also consider having a look at third party dataGrids, in case the standard DataGrid doesn't cover all of your needs, but with individual Templating you can get pretty far.

Comment: The WPF DataGrid also have a expandable details view available for each row Template is the property: `DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, by "expand" you mean to show sth under a line (or specifically, a list view item)?

If it is the case, in your data template, add a stackpanel, for instance, and change its Visibility to collaped;

by clicking on the "+" button, change the collaped to visible.

```
<ListView ...>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <GridView ...>
           <Button Name="ExpandButton Click="OnClick"/>
       <StackPane  Visibility={Binding SomeProperty} />
   <Itemtemplate>
</ListView>
```

In Onclick, change the SomeProperty=Visibility.Visible. I assume you are comfortable with data binding in WPF.

Comment: I have tried this solution but I didn't manage to get the link between the button and the corresponding stack panel... Do you know how to do that ?